# use patch method to update model in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to update a customer using patch methodn here is my route

```php
Route::patch('/customers/updateCustomer', 'CustomerController@update')
    ->name('customers.update');
```

and here is my form :

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.update') }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
```

how to pass the id of the customer , the update method requires two parameters, when the first one is the data from the from , the second should be the id of the customer

Comment: add it to your route by separating it with a comma. try this: `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.update',$customer->id) }}">`

Answer (score 1):

You should send the customer id with the `route()` helper function.

> Make sure to send the customer object during the form rendering.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.update', $customer['id']) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
```

And modify the route slightly.

```
Route::patch('/customers/updateCustomer/{customerId}', 'CustomerController@update')->name('customers.update');
```

Answer (score 1):

add customer id to the route like

```
Route::patch('/customers/updateCustomer/{id}', 'CustomerController@update')->name('customers.update');
```

and then your form action should be like

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.update',$customer->id) }}">
```

you have to send the customer object from where you are returning to the form. 
and finally your update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //your things to do
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.update',['id'=>$customer->id]) }}">
```

And your route should be

```
Route::patch('/customers/updateCustomer/{id}', 'CustomerController@update')->name('customers.update');
```

And your controller should be

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    //your code

}
```